# Can I have multiple chroot directories?

Tags: apache-2.2

Currently my users are chrooted to `/srv/www`, but I want to give my users access to another directory `/Zend/`. Is there a way to do this?

I am using Debian 6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, chroot's designed to not let this happen unless you explicitly do something to make one of the directories appear as a true descendant of the other (not with a symlink).

This can be done in various ways on various Unix-likes (for example, with null mounts in FreeBSD).  [The ProFTPd chroot reference page](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Chroot.html) has a nice summary of doing this on various systems:

```
Linux (as of the 2.4.0 kernel):
  mount --bind /var/ftp/incoming /home/bob/incoming
  mount --bind /var/ftp/incoming /home/dave/incoming
or, alternatively:
  mount -o bind /var/ftp/incoming /home/bob/incoming
  mount -o bind /var/ftp/incoming /home/dave/incoming
BSD (as of 4.4BSD):
  mount_null /var/ftp/incoming /home/bob/incoming
  mount_null /var/ftp/incoming /home/dave/incoming
Solaris:
  mount -F lofs /var/ftp/incoming /home/bob/incoming
  mount -F lofs /var/ftp/incoming /home/dave/incoming
```

**EDIT:** Adding some Debian-specific detail, your mount might be something like:

```
mount -o bind /true/path/to/Zend /srv/www/Zend
```

... which would show up as `/Zend` if your users are chrooted to `/srv/www`.

Comment: I have Debian 6 btw.

Comment: Debian should support `mount -o bind` -- see http://wiki.debian.org/chroot

Comment: Today, I learned more about fstab, and mount. Amazing resource link!